# Express JS redirect to default page instead of "Cannot GET"

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express JS and I have a set of routes that I have defined as follows

```
require('./moduleA/routes')(app);
require('./moduleB/routes')(app);
```

and so on. If I try to access any of the routes that I have not defined in the above routes, say

```
http://localhost:3001/test
```

it says

```
Cannot GET /test/
```

But instead of this I want to redirect to my app's index page. I want this redirection to happen to all of the undefined routes. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try to add the following route as the last route:

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

***Edit:***

After a little researching I concluded that it's better to use `app.get` instead of `app.use`:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

because `app.use` handles all HTTP methods (`GET`, `POST`, etc.), and you probably don't want to make undefined `POST` requests redirect to index page.

Comment: @Srivathsa you're welcome) Sorry for my rash answer, it's better to use `app.get`. Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks ! Helpful

Answer (score 3):

JUst try to put one `get` handler with `*` after all your get handlers like bellow.

```
app.get('/', routes.getHomePage);//When `/` get the home page

app.get('/login',routes.getLoginPage); //When `/login` get the login page

app.get('*',routes.getHomePage); // when  any other of these both then also homepage.
```

But make sure `*` should be after all, otherwise those will not work which are after `*` handler.

Comment: Just for your information: this solution leads to [duplicate content](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2049078/What-is-Duplicate-Content), because there would be several pages with the same content, and this is bad for SEO. It's better to use HTTP redirection instead.

Answer (score 0):

HTML file would be :

```
<form class="" action="/fail" method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="button">Redirect to Homepage!</button>
</form>
```

Your Node.js code would be:

```
app.post("/fail", (req, res)=>{  
  res.redirect("/"); 
});
```